# Why does the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus need to be applied to derive the power rule for integration?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, definition, indefinite-integrals

On Wikipedia, the article about the [power rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule#Statement_of_the_power_rule) states that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x)=x^n$, then

$$
f'(x)=nx^{n-1}
$$

provided that $f$ is differentiable at $x$, $n$ is a constant, and $x$ is a variable. The article then goes on to say that applying the fundamental theorem of calculus allows us to derive the power rule for integration:

$$
\int x^ndx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C
$$

I don't understand how the fundamental theorem of calculus is relevant here. I have often read that the fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that 'integration is the reverse process to differentiation', but I assumed that this was referring to *definite integration*. For example, the first fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt=f(x)
$$

This is a crucially important result that relates *finding the area* with *finding the gradient*, but (as far as I understand) says nothing about indefinite integrals. Surely the fact that

$$
\int\left(\frac{d}{dx}x^n\right)dx=x^n+C
$$

is pretty much true by definition, and is by no means an interesting result that deserves the name 'fundamental'. Indefinite integration (or finding the antiderivative)  *means* 'what differentiates to the integrand'? The fundamental theorem of calculus is only interesting because it shows the link between *finding the area* and *finding the antiderivative*, which is not immediately apparent. However, because the power rule only deals with indefinite integration, can't it be proved with no appeal to the fundamental theorem of calculus? Here is an attempt:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{d}{dx}(x^{n+1})=\frac{n+1}{n+1}x^n=x^n
$$

The indefinite integral of $x^n$ means 'what function (or family of functions) differentiate to $x^n$?' Therefore,

$$
\int x^ndx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C
$$

Comment: You're right. That section of that wikipedia page is badly written, and should be changed.

Comment: Integration is no longer defined as anti-differentiation, not for the last 100 years or so. Nowadays there are two independent standalone ideas: derivatives and integrals, both quite deep ideas. The Fundamental Theorem relates them, and justifies the old idea of anti-derivative.

Comment: @ancientmathematician In fact, there exist functions for which the derivatives exist and are everywhere bounded but nowhere Riemann integrable..

Comment: Wikipedia is generally nice on math topics, but this one seems to have been written casually. Hope someone will fix it.

Comment: If you simply define the integral as the "inverse" of differentiation (I say "inverse" in quotes since technically we cannot truly have an inverse derivative, since the answer is not unique because of the additive constant) then yeah, there is no need to invoke the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. The role of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is simply to essentially relate areas and derivatives, from which the use of an integral naturally pops out

Comment: Hey, I am the nose of the guy that made an integral definition - you can trust me! ;)